# Ошибка при передаче данных через COM порт

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, com-порт

Ниже приведено общение двух программ с COM-портом (вывод *portmon*).

1. В первой программе все хорошо:

   ```
     # |    Time    |     Process     |            Request            |   Port    |  Result   |    Other
   ----+------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------
     2 | 0.01203070 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJ_CREATE                 | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Option: Open
     3 | 0.00002697 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE    | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
     4 | 0.00001926 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
     5 | 0.00001918 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_GET_CHARS               | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
     6 | 0.00001835 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
     7 | 0.00374957 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE    | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Rate:9600
     8 | 0.00296898 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_CLR_DTR          | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
     9 | 0.00296159 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | StopBits:1 Parity:EVEN WordLength:8
    10 | 0.00398015 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHAR         | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | EOF:0 ERR:0 BRK:0 EVT:0 XON:0 XOFF:0
    11 | 0.00396349 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Shake:0 Replace:80 XonLimit:0 XoffLimit:0
    12 | 0.00002385 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK    | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Mask: RXCHAR
    13 | 34.9157... | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    14 | 0.00104099 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJ_WRITE                  | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 3: 53 54 2A
    15 | 0.00003547 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    16 | 0.00000564 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 53
    17 | 0.00071164 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    18 | 0.00002305 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    19 | 0.00000529 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 54
    20 | 0.00076436 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    21 | 0.00002774 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    22 | 0.00000440 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 2A
    23 | 0.00077897 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    24 | 0.00002229 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    25 | 0.00000523 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 45
    26 | 0.00177510 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    27 | 0.00002837 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    28 | 0.00000415 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 31
    29 | 0.00178087 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    30 | 0.00003272 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    31 | 0.00000526 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 2: 36 2A
    32 | 0.00047031 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    33 | 0.00002256 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_COMMSTATUS   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    34 | 0.00000520 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 07
    35 | 24.2991... | SMC-Program-v-3 | IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK     | Silabser0 | CANCELLED |
    36 | 0.00001899 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJCLEANUP                 | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    37 | 0.00880000 | SMC-Program-v-3 | IRP_MJCLOSE                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
   ```
2. А вторая не работает — устройство присылает ошибку:

   ```
     # |    Time    |   Process    |            Request            |   Port    |  Result   |    Other
   ----+------------+--------------+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------
    38 | 0.01200985 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_CREATE                 | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Option: Open
    39 | 0.00002110 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE    | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    40 | 0.00001432 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    41 | 0.00001334 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_GET_CHARS               | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    42 | 0.00001324 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    43 | 0.00001286 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE    | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    44 | 0.00001286 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    45 | 0.00001296 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_GET_CHARS               | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    46 | 0.00001325 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    47 | 0.00389782 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE    | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Rate:9600
    48 | 0.00298407 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_CLR_DTR          | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    49 | 0.00292257 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | StopBits:1 Parity:NONE WordLength:8
    50 | 0.00398163 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHAR         | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | EOF:0 ERR:0 BRK:0 EVT:0 XON:0 XOFF:0
    51 | 0.00397269 | usb-com1.exe | IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW     | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Shake:0 Replace:80 XonLimit:0 XoffLimit:0
    52 | 0.05203023 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_WRITE                  | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 3: 53 54 2A
    53 | 0.00292054 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 45
    54 | 0.00223534 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 3: 31 35 2A
    55 | 0.00094102 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 07
    56 | 0.00196109 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 95
    57 | 0.00001190 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 45
    58 | 0.00000510 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 31
    59 | 0.00000470 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 35
    60 | 0.00000441 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 2A
    61 | 0.00000473 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   | Length 1: 07
    62 | 0.20059002 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJ_READ                   | Silabser0 | CANCELLED | Length 1
    63 | 0.00001956 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJCLEANUP                 | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
    37 | 0.00911579 | usb-com1.exe | IRP_MJCLOSE                   | Silabser0 | SUCCESS   |
   ```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело? Что надо изменить в моей программе? На мой взгляд дело в MASK-e, но как её менять? И вообще, это маска чего?

Код:

```
void open_port(char * name);
void close_port();

DWORD __stdcall ReadThread(LPVOID hwnd);

bool write_scc(LPCVOID outputData,
               const unsigned int& sizeBuffer,
               unsigned long& length); 

BOOL read_scc(LPVOID inputData,
              const unsigned int& sizeBuffer,
              unsigned long& length); 


HANDLE hCom = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
HANDLE hThread; 
HWND hwnd;
DCB dcb; 

int main() {
    std::cout << "<=SERIAL PORT=>\n\n";
    unsigned int a = 3 * sizeof(char); // сколько отправить
    unsigned long b;                   // сколько получаем в ответ
    char TextIn[4]; 
    char TextOut[5] = "ST*";
    char sPortName[] = "COM5";

    // сперва открываем порт
    open_port(sPortName);

    write_scc((void*)TextOut, a, b);   // запись в порт     
    read_scc((void*)TextIn, a, b);
    std::cout << std::endl << "prinjali:" << TextIn;

    close_port();// в конце работы закрываем порт
    std::cout << "     \n"
              << "***" << b << std::endl
              << TextIn;
    return 0;
}

void open_port(char *name) {
    // (имя порта, права доступа, 0, 0) - открытие порта, с указанием прав
    hCom = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
                      OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    // Если порт открыт ошибкой(порт не открыт)
    if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        std::cout << " *** Error opening port!\n";
        getch();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << " *** Port succesfully opened!\n";

        // Функция GetCommState извлекает данные о текущих настройках
        // управляющих сигналов для указанного коммуникационного устройства.

        dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
        dcb.ByteSize = 8;
        dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
        dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

        if (SetCommState(hCom, &dcb))
            std::cout << " *** Configuring OK.\n\n";
        else
            std::cout << " *** Configuring error.\n\n";

        hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, ReadThread, (LPVOID)hwnd, 0, 0);
    }
}

void close_port() {
    if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;

    TerminateThread(hThread, 0);
    CloseHandle(hCom);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    std::cout << "\n *** Port succesfully closed!\n";

    hCom = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

DWORD __stdcall ReadThread(LPVOID hwnd) {
    DWORD iSize;
    char sReceivedChar;

    while (true)
    {
        ReadFile(hCom, &sReceivedChar, 1, &iSize, 0);
        // SendDlgItemMessage((HWND)hwnd, IDC_EDIT2, WM_CHAR, sReceivedChar, 0);
        std::cout << sReceivedChar << ""; ///поместить разделитель
    }
}

bool write_scc( LPCVOID outputData,
                const unsigned int& sizeBuffer,
                unsigned long& length)
{
    if (&length) {
        if (WriteFile(hCom,               // handle to file to write to
                      outputData,         // pointer to data to write to file
                      sizeBuffer,         // number of bytes to write
                      &length,NULL) == 0) // pointer to number of bytes written
        {
            printf("Reading of serial communication has problem.");
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    } 

    return FALSE;
}


BOOL read_scc( LPVOID inputData,
               const unsigned int& sizeBuffer,
               unsigned long& length)
{
    if (ReadFile(hCom,       // handle of file to read
                 inputData,  // handle of file to read
                 sizeBuffer, // number of bytes to read
                 &length,    // pointer to number of bytes read
                 NULL) == 0) // pointer to structure for data
    {
        printf("Reading of serial communication has problem 1.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (&length) {
        inputData[length] = NULL; // Assign end flag of message.
        return TRUE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: У Вас разные настройки порта, если я правильно понял лог. В одном случае четность -- EVEN (бит чётности), в другом -- NONE (без него). Третье возможное значение -- ODD (бит нечётности).

У Вас `dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;`

Ежели мне не изменяет склероз, то настроить порт Вы можете как из программы (самое правильное), так и извне её (например в сессии cmd.exe)

http://www.robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf

Comment: @alexlz, точно! спасибо, что нашли эту ошибку!

а Mask: RXCHAR может влиять на сигнал, который отдаем? или она лишь на прием влияет?

Comment: @alexlz, а то, что не видит сигналов-странно.. он же отвечает. хоть и ошибками, но отвечает

Comment: Разная длина посылки. В одном случае -- 1(start)+8(data)+1(even)+1(stop) -- 11 бит. В другом -- 10 бит. Если бит even==0 (если не путаю -- уже подзабыл), то за него может сойти stop-bit (при побайтном обмене start будет ещё не скоро). Если нет -- то имеем на стороне устройства ошибку чётности.

 http://i.imgur.com/Goat8lN.png

Comment: @alexlz, вы были абсолютно правы! вся загвоздка была именно в этом! все заработало:)

Comment: Поздравляю

Answer (score 2):

*Из комментария пользователя [@alexlz](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352/alexlz):*

У Вас разные настройки порта, если я правильно понял лог. В одном случае четность `EVEN` (бит чётности), в другом — `NONE` (без него). Третье возможное значение — `ODD` (бит нечётности). У Вас `dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;`. Ежели мне не изменяет склероз, то настроить порт Вы можете как из программы (самое правильное), так и извне её (например в сессии `cmd.exe`)

Подробнее о работе с COM-портами можно прочитать в статье  «[Windows Serial Port Programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20120905123232/http://robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf)» за авторством Робертсона Байера.